# Can this extension of $\sf ZFC^-$ intepret Mac Lane set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\sf ZFC^-$ be the theory $``\sf ZF + R \text{ well orders } V- Power"$ (where $\sf R$ is a primitive binay relation symbol).

- Can $\sf ``ZFC^- + \exists \aleph_\omega"$ interpret Mac Lane set theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Mac Lane set theory is a theory obtained from Zermelo set theory $\mathsf{Z}$ by restricting Separation to $\Delta_0$-formulas, then yes.

You can see that the usual proof of $V=L\to\mathsf{GCH}$, which uses condensation lemma, still carries over $\mathsf{ZFC^-}$, and the same proof shows $\aleph_\omega$ in $L$ is a strong limit, that is, $L_{\omega_\omega}$ is closed under a power set. Hence $L_{\omega_\omega}$ satisfies $\mathsf{Z}$ with Powerset.

Comment: would that entail that any extension of $\sf ZF$ of the form $\sf ZF + \exists \aleph_\kappa$ that is compatible with global choice would be interpretable in $\sf ZFC^- + \exists \aleph_\kappa$

Comment: @Zuhair No, even if what you mean is $\mathsf{ZF^-}$ instead of $\mathsf{ZF}$. My proof does not work if your extension is not compatible with $V=L$.

Comment: yes, actually that what was on my mind, compatibility with $V=L$, so it works for any extension compatible with $V=L$.